# Is this a Valid DateFormat in Java

Tags: java, date

I want to parse this date "Mon Mar 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" in java SimpleDateFormat class as "MM-dd-yyyy", is this a valid date format? If yes, how can I do that?

```
String inputDate = "Wed Sep 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
//SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"); -- Not working
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z"); // Not Working
Date date = sdf.parse(inputDate);
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Comment: can I do that with java internal library or it will require external library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried following piece of code:

```
String inputDate = "Wed Sep 17 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z"); 
Date date = sdf.parse(inputDate);
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Output:
2014-09-17

Comment: thanks a lot... it works and you saved me from from adding any extra librray

Answer (score 0):

Try by using this format "**E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z**"  with SimpleDateFormat class.

Comment: Gives me parse exception